# How to Authenticate users by google ID to use script gadgets on sites.google.com/mysite?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I would like to host my webpage using google sites. The page will contain gadgets of google scripts. I would like to request the user to login using google id and use the user information in my scripts.

Do you know how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish the script so that it executes as "User executing the web app" and is available to "Anyone" you will get precisely this behavior, no need for further work.